# Log processing with regerx and slice

Tags: python

I have a log partner as below i just want to be separate it those are in between [] bracket including time from the beginning. have tried below code as well but no luck .

```
def crop_string(line):
    try:
        #str0 = line.replace(']',"")
        #str1 = str0.replace('.000+05:30',"")
        str2 = line.split()
        #str2 = list(dict.fromkeys(str1))
        #x = len(str2)
        print(str2[0],str2[5])
        pass
    except IndexError:
        print("exception",str2)
        pass
```

log

```
"INFO:DEL:2018-11-24T14:04:49.000+05:30 bltxn03 ChannelGatewayRequestLog INFO   :: [ReqOut:][RQID:1958259][STV:1RC][S:EXTGW][RQC:17007][UN:banti mobile centre ][CAT:RET][MSISDN:334455668][USt:Y][UNW:UW][DSMS:1RC 44xxxxxx 11111.0 VG ****][TEMPTID:null][UDH:313231][ST:EXTGW][SRVPRT:190][OINFO:RETAPPUW,MsgReq=true,FT=R ResTyp=RESPONSE][RETMSG:<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE COMMAND PUBLIC "-//Ocam//DTD XML Command 1.0//EN" "xml/command.dtd"><COMMAND><TYPE>EXRC121TRFRESP</TYPE><TXNSTATUS>17007</TXNSTATUS><DATE>4/10/2018 14:04:49</DATE><EXTREFNUM>192108828_1548487626</EXTREFNUM><TXNID>UW445566126</TXNID><MESSAGE>Your request cannot be processed at this time, please try again later.</MESSAGE></COMMAND>][FixdInfNtAvail.][TT:860 ms]"
```

Comment: What does "no luck" mean? If this does not work, what happens instead? Do you get an error? (Please do not answer in a comment. Use [edit] to add all missing information to your question.)

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall` should do the trick. Check the code snippet below to see, how it could be used with non-greedy regular expressions.
Still, I advise you avoiding such simple solutions: string data containing brackets can lead to incorrect results.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function
import re


def crop_string(line):
    log_time = re.search(r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}", line)
    if log_time is None:
        raise Exception("The line doesn't include a timestamp")
    log_brackets_list = re.findall("\[(.*?)\]", line)
    return log_time.group(0), log_brackets_list


if __name__ == '__main__':

    time, brackets_list = crop_string("""INFO:DEL:2018-11-24T14:04:49.000+05:30 bltxn03 ChannelGatewayRequestLog INFO   :: [ReqOut:][RQID:1958259][STV:1RC][S:EXTGW][RQC:17007][UN:banti mobile centre ][CAT:RET][MSISDN:334455668][USt:Y][UNW:UW][DSMS:1RC 44xxxxxx 11111.0 VG ****][TEMPTID:null][UDH:313231][ST:EXTGW][SRVPRT:190][OINFO:RETAPPUW,MsgReq=true,FT=R ResTyp=RESPONSE][RETMSG:<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE COMMAND PUBLIC "-//Ocam//DTD XML Command 1.0//EN" "xml/command.dtd"><COMMAND><TYPE>EXRC121TRFRESP</TYPE><TXNSTATUS>17007</TXNSTATUS><DATE>4/10/2018 14:04:49</DATE><EXTREFNUM>192108828_1548487626</EXTREFNUM><TXNID>UW445566126</TXNID><MESSAGE>Your request cannot be processed at this time, please try again later.</MESSAGE></COMMAND>][FixdInfNtAvail.][TT:860 ms]""")
    print(time, brackets_list)
```